# ConcurrentModificationException when post a object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I run a post for the first time (when the id is not yet saved in the database) it is returning "ConcurrentModificationException: null";

```
dto.getObservations().stream()
                .map(productObservationsService::convertDTOToModel)
                .forEach(model::addObservation);
```

and this is my entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "relatedProduct", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private List<ProductObservationModel> observations;

public void addObservation(ProductObservationModel observationModel) {
    if (this.observations == null)
        this.observations = new ArrayList<>();

    observations.add(observationModel);
    observationModel.setRelatedProduct(this);
}
```

Does anyone know what can it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be completely honest i dont know what you mean with "When I run a post for the first time (when the id is not yet saved in the database)".

Your Problem is that you are trying to write to a List while iterating over it that was not made for that (observations).

If the list is always provided by you, you can change
`this.observations = new ArrayList<>()`
to
`this.observations = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>()`.
You can read more on how the List works on the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

If not you can copy the list before iterating or saving the added ProductObservationModel in a additional List and add them after iterating.

```
new ArrayList<>(dto.getObservations()).stream()
            .map(productObservationsService::convertDTOToModel)
            .forEach(model::addObservation);
```

Comment: sorry for my bad english, i tried this solution and i get the same error.

Comment: Which one did you try? Can i get the full stacktrace?

Comment: both alternatives

Comment: Can i get the full stacktrace?

Comment: sorry for the fake, i cleared my ide cache and it worked, thanks so much

Comment: Just out of curiosity does it work with my changes or without?

Comment: With its solutions, more precisely the second option.